# Has the paradigm of interpretation of the 20th century as "short" been criticized in historiography?

Tags: 20th-century

In "The Age Of Extremes: 1914-1994 " Hobsbawm describes those years as "short" as opposed to the long 19th century. Is there any historiographic source that criticized this kind of distinction?

Comment: Since cinema was invented in the late 1880's, and the fall of the twin towers can be compared to that of the Berlin wall, one can speak of a long twentieth century, lasting from the Lumiere age to the Iraq war, for instance; or, conversely, one might speak of a long twenty-first century, starting with the Perestroika; etc.

Comment: History doesn't nicely align with centuries.  It makes sense to pick important dates near the beginning and ending to characterize the century.  1914-1994 is a nice range because it mostly contains the battles between the fascist, communist and capitalistic ideologies for control.   But it really depends on what story you are telling.

Comment: This is more a matter of organising book chapters than rigorous historical scholarship, I don't think it's really a paradigm or a subject of historiography.